# Get underlying element in jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to attach a jQuery dialog to it's current parent (let's say, because it contains inputs and it's parent is a child in the form).
So the problem is illustrated here:

http://jsfiddle.net/pprrm4st/2/

I definetly need to find a `.container` of the current element and attach the dialog to it.

```
appendTo: $(this).closest('.container'), //I thougnt $(this) would be current .element
```

Otherwise is there a way to tell jQuery not to move `.element` nowhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is not the element in that scope, you should note that there are no function calls that would set the `this`value.

Here's how to solve it using an `each` loop, where `this` would be the element etc.

```
$(".element").each(function() {
    $(this).dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        appendTo: $(this).closest('.container'),
        buttons: {
            "I've read and understand this": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});

$('a').click(function(){
    $(".element").dialog('open');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/pprrm4st/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This also does the trick if you don't wanna have a loop:

```
$(".element").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        "I've read and understand this": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
}).dialog( "option", "appendTo", $(".element").closest('.container') );

$('a').click(function(){
    $(".element").dialog('open');
});
```

or even shorter (and cheaper, because you only traverse once the DOM looking for `.element`):

```
var elem = $(".element")

elem.dialog({
    modal: true,
    appendTo: elem.closest('.container'),
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        "I've read and understand this": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
})

$('a').click(function(){
    elem.dialog('open');
});
```